# Top menubar has disappeared across all apps - not just full screen

Tags: menu-bar

I believe that I typed some keyboard combination in a fullscreen app to hide the top menu bar.  Methinks it were Adobe Reader, but uncertain at this point

Actually even *that* did not do what was intended:  it just put blank space where the menu bar had been - it did not reclaim that space for anything useful.

Now the menubar is gone for *all* apps.

Any way to unhide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by a highly technical approach: rebooting ..

Answer (score 1):

move the mouse pointer as high as possible on the left upper corner os the display screen, this will make the top bar of the application visible, click the round green dot and the application will be smaller, so that you have the top menubar visible again.

Comment: i'll remember that next time - and if it works award it. For now i rebooted and the problem went away.